# A new answer provides a better solution to the accepted one; can I edit the accepted answer and paraphrase the new one?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

I have found a question where the accepted answer is correct, but out-of-date.  A newer answer gives a better solution for more recent versions of the library.  I am neither the asker nor the answerer, but I thought it might help people like me if I edit the accepted answer with something along the lines of "Since version xxx, you can do this: [new answer]; The original solution for previous verions is [old answer]", as I have seen done on other questions.

What is the etiquette here?  I think it would be valuable to copy the newer answer into the accepted answer (obviously citing the user responsible) but I am also aware the user will not gain reputation for their answer as a result.  Or, could I edit the question say something along the lines of "See xxxx's answer below since version xxx"?

Comment: Do you have full edit rights? If not, leave a comment  first?

Comment: @rene Yes, I have full edit rights.  But I've never edited someone else's answer before!

Comment: Perhaps leave a comment and hope the original answerer does the decent thing and edits it him/herself. Of course that only works if they are still active on the site.

Comment: Will do.  Seems like edits I've seen on other questions are not the preferred approach!

Answer (score 11):

Please don't - while the ideal is to have the selected answer to be correct, we *rarely* edit the answers of others and make *significant* changes. The intent of the person who posted the elected answer, and the work of the person who posted the better answer is not respected.

*Rather* - I'd suggest leaving a comment below the selected answer "If you're running version 11.01 of foo you might want to take a look at the answer of user 1234 - which works better". Include a link of course. Upvote the better answer, and you've done all you should be doing.

An *exception* would be community wikis - which are posts which are shared by the community. They're less common but in many cases, meta FAQs would count as such.

Comment: The exception to this is meta FAQs, whose top answers *should* be edited with new information in case the system or community consensus changes. This is because FAQs are intended as documentation, and having incorrect or consensus-contradicting information in them can be bad.